# Basics - help with resistance reading

Tags: resistance, continuity

I'm trying to solve an issue with my eletric radiator and more specifically either the heating element or control panel (circuit board.)

I've tested the element with a multimeter and it is showing what I believe to be the correct resistance but when I do the continuity test the sound is intermittent (like a really quick morse code.)

Does that sound like a bad element and is there another way to make sure?

Regarding the resistance cals. It is a 1500W/230V element with a resistance of 35.8ohms. I work out it should be about 35.2ohms.  Is it within limits?

The new panel is over £150 and can't be refunded if I buy it which is why I'd like to make sure.

Comment: You haven't disclosed what the issue is.

Comment: There is no generic explanation about what your meter does in continuity mode. Read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

35.8Ω is exactly 35.2Ω for engineering purposes, and certainly for a commercial product that just has to produce more or less the right amount of heat, something midway between 1 kW and 2 kW.

Continuity mode on a meter should produce an indication when the probes are shorted together, and not when they're not. That's the only behaviour that's guaranteed for continuity mode. Most meters will also produce an indication for small resistances of a few ohms, perhaps a few 10s of ohms, depending on how the meter designer was feeling at the time. With 35Ω, I would not be surprised at any behaviour from the meter on the continuity setting, including going on and off. Does your meter have a datasheet where it specifies what the continuity limits are? Don't bin your heater on the strength of the meter beeping.

If you want to measure what your heater element is doing, use the resistance function. That's intended to tell the difference between 35 and 36 ohms. Watch the resistance reading while you gently tap your heater, that should show up any breaks in the circuit.

Do bear in mind that equipment intended for mains use may have connectors that read open circuit when a very low voltage is applied, such as that of a DMM. Under normal use, the high voltage will break down any insulating film that has formed on the surface of the connectors from contamination in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tested the element with a multimeter and it is showing what I believe to be the correct resistance but when I do the continuity test the sound is intermittent (like a really quick Morse code.)

This can't be answered with the information provided. Your "continuity mode" may be the diode test function or it may be a special resistance mode where resistance below a certain value gives a continuous beep, and other values give beeps or no output. Read the manual!

> Does that sound like a bad element and is there another way to make sure?

No. The resistance measurement is an adequate test.

> It is a 1500W/230V element with a resistance of 35.8ohms. I work out it should be about 35.2ohms. Is it within limits?

The heater will be designed to work with a wide voltage tolerance - typically +10% to -6% in Europe according to a quick web search. This variation will swamp the 1.7% error between your measurement and calculation. In addition, you have, I presume, measured the cold resistance. The resistance will increase quite a lot when hot resulting in a lower current and power.